# PHP array is not saving two last elements

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to copy from one array to another but only unique values. I use for loop and when I debug all 10 blues are shown but after for loop the last 2 values are gone.

I debug each array element during the "for loop" and it seems fine coz I see all 10 elements. The problem starts after the for loop. E.g. If I want to print the 9th element it doesn't print it, i.e. it shows emty.

What can be the proble?

P.S> I've tried array_unique(), same output so its not it.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php

session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); //to remove annoying notices

include 'connectDB.php';

$queryISBN = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM booksread");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($queryISBN);
if($numrows!=0)
{   
    $isbn_array = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryISBN))
    {
        $isbn_array[]=$row['ISBN'];
    }

    $isbn_unique = array();

    for ($i=0;$i<count($isbn_array );$i++)
    {
        if(!in_array($isbn_array[$i],$isbn_unique ))
        {
            $isbn_unique[$i]=$isbn_array[$i];
            echo $isbn_unique[$i]."  ---- ";
        }
    }
}
echo "<h1>Select books you would like to view</h1>";
$submit = $_POST['submit'];

if(isset($_POST['selectedbooks']))
    {
        $checked = $_POST['selectedbooks'];
    }

if($submit)
    {
        if(!isset($checked))
        {
            echo "You must check at least one book.";
        }
        else 
        {
            $_SESSION['checked'] = $checked;
            header("location: view_entries_results.php");
        }
    }

?>

<html>
<body>

<form action="view_entries.php" method="POST">
<table>
<table border="1">
<th>ISBN<th>Title<th>Author<th>Select</th>

<?php
    echo "Arr size: ".count($isbn_unique )." </br>";
    echo "8: ".$isbn_unique[7]."</br>";
    for ($j=0;$j<count($isbn_unique );$j++)
    {
        $curElement = $isbn_unique[$j];
        echo "Cur el: ".$curElement;
        $queryBook = mysql_query("SELECT * from book WHERE ISBN='$curElement'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryBook))
        {   
            $ISBN = $row['ISBN'];
            $title = $row['Title'];
            $author = $row['Authorname'];
        }
        ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $ISBN; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $author; ?></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectedbooks[]" value="<?php echo $ISBN; ?>"/>
    </tr>

   <?php }  ?>

</table>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Entry" /></p>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED THANKS TO helloxk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
if(!in_array($isbn_array[$i],$isbn_unique ))
{
    $isbn_unique[$i] = $isbn_array[$i];
    echo $isbn_unique[$i]."  ---- ";
}
```

should be

```
if(!in_array($isbn_array[$i],$isbn_unique ))
{
    $isbn_unique[] = $isbn_array[$i];
    echo $isbn_array[$i]."  ---- ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have  duplicate values in $isbn_array, so its skip keys as its already in array and hence size of $isbn_unique is different then then the $isbn_array. Try to debug on that.